# Binarize a list with lists inside

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I am trying to binarize a list (keep the 0 as 0, and convert any other number to 1) like (example of the format, real list much longer):

```py
d = [[0,0,192],[0,0,0,0,56],[...],...]

With len(d) = 23473 and len(d[n])=300, so kind of a lot of data
```

Is there any way to do it not with two loops? I tried it and it takes a lot of time and converts the list to lenght>>23473

```py
#for i in np.linspace(0,len(d)-1,len(d),dtype=int):
#    for k in np.linspace(0,len(d[i])-1,len(d[i]),dtype=int):
#        if d[i][k] != 0:
#            d[i][k] = 1
#        else:
#            d[i][k] = 0
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: look at numpy.where

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the fact that `int(bool(x))` is `0` for `0` and `1` for anything else:

```py
d = [[0, 0, 192], [0, 0, 0, 0, 56]]

d = [[int(bool(x)) for x in l] for l in d]

print(d)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

If you're already using numpy (as your own attempted solution suggests), you can just use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) like this:

```py
import numpy as np

d = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 0, 4], [5, 6, 0]])
d = np.where(d == 0, 0, 1)

print(d)
```